# Is it possible to swim 125 km in week?

Tags: training, swimming, endurance

Simple question, can a swimmer train and swim 125 km in week? Just curious to know if it is possible that a swimmer can train and swim 125 km every week, week in week out?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78313/discussion-on-question-by-kyloren-is-it-possible-to-swim-125-km-in-week).

Comment: My personal opinion, a question about the limits of the human body ARE about the fitness.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s possible. Is it possible for the vast majority of people? No. Is it beneficial? No. How long would it take? 52 hours at a pace of 2.5 minutes per 100 meters.

Here is one guy that could do it.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Strel

Comment: I can't see how it would not be beneficial? And I doubt very much that anyone who can only swim 2.5 minutes per 100m would even be able to complete the distance stated week in week out.

Comment: It is said that Michael Phelps swims 80 km a week in a total of 36 hours. I guess if you were about as fit as him but specialised in long distance-swimming yes it would be possible to swim 125 km, but resulting in about 9 hours of swimming 6 days a week I do not think it is sustainable

Comment: @Gimli, Phelps is a middle distance swimmer and his training is much different than a distance swimmer. 4 hours per day and 5 hours on the 6th day, with kick and medley thrown in is all you need.